# Replace varying lengths of periods with np.NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where the NaN values are expressed in arbitrary lengths of periods.

ex. df =

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3
0    ...   val1   ....
1   val2      .   val3
```

How would I change all these "period cells" to np.NaN? Using df.replace('...', np.NaN) right now but I have to do it for each type of "period cell" that shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   ...  val1  ....
1  val2     .  val3

In [8]: df = df.replace(r'^\.+$', np.nan, regex=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   NaN  val1   NaN
1  val2   NaN  val3
```